# Flutter: Do I need to call GestureRecognizer.dispose in StatelessWidget (TextSpan/recognizer)?

Tags: flutter

I am reading this doc page: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/TextSpan/recognizer.html.

The example included in this page is a StatefulWidget and the doc says `The code that owns the GestureRecognizer object must call GestureRecognizer.dispose when the TextSpan object is no longer used.`.

I am wondering if I can use the `recognizer` of `TextSpan` in a StatelessWidget?

If so, do I need to call `dispose` somewhere? I have no idea where to call it.

Comment: This one too!! I mean what's the purpose of editing without the need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in a `StatelessWidget`. You will have to convert it into a `StatefulWidget` and override the `dispose` method of `State`:

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  GestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    gestureRecognizer?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I use it in a StatelessWidget? I use it inside a stateless widget in my current code, it works fine and I don't find any problems at all. Will this cause memory leak?

Comment: Yes, you will have memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. (1) But other than concept, how can I test if this actually causes memory leaks? Is there any easy ways to prove it? Otherwise, I have to trust this blindly. (2) What about other tappable widgets such as `InkWell`? Do they have to put inside StatefulWidget? If not, why is `GestureRecognizer` so different? I am really curious about this because I nearly never use any StatefulWidget. I am following bloc state management, so all my widgets are Stateless with StreamBuilder. Thanks again.

Comment: `InkWell` internally has a `StatefulWidget` used to dispose the recognizer. You can test it by using the `Observatory`, although it is not very documented

Comment: Also you need a `StatefulWidget` with `BLoC` to dispose the BLoC itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Can I ask where I can find an article teaching about when to dispose BLoC? I really never dispose anything. I have no ideas when I should do it. I always think all my UI streams should keep alive to listen and update the state. I don't really understand why I should dispose it and when I want to kill the stream. Even [the official BLoC example code ](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/tree/master/shared/lib/src/bloc) is not calling dispose methods. I am really confused with all `dispose` actions and really want to understand it clearly.

Comment: That's kinda off-topic and hard to answer in comment. Consider making a new SO question focused on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I have mark it as the answer. Regarding the dispose question, because I can only ask a new question in 90 minutes. So I have to wait 90 minutes to create another one. After 90m, I will create a new question and put link here. If you have time, please show me some directions in the new question. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773248/ You can take a look when you have time. I know the question is very complex and will take a lot of time to answer. Thanks.