# Flutter: when should I dispose BLoC?

Tags: flutter

When should I dispose BLoC?

Even in the official bloc [example code](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/tree/master/shared/lib/src/bloc), it creates `dispose` methods for the BLoC class, but they never gets called.

Comment: What was the point of editing the question?

Answer (score 6):

In the specific example you've referenced, the BLoC wouldn't need to be disposed of manually because it needs to be accessible throughout the lifetime of the app so will get disposed of when the app gets disposed. There is a [comment to this effect in CartProvider.dart](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/blob/9ee5a631ef7cf3e891c5deea230878b7ed066a39/shared/lib/src/bloc/cart_provider.dart#L10).

If your BLoC is only used by a portion of your app then you should definitely be disposing it. For the example you posted you would probably want to wrap the `CartProvider` inside a `StatefulWidget` and then dispose of it within the dispose method of that `StatefulWidget`'s `State` object.