# Killing flutter gesture

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to stop a gesture from continuing if a certain criteria is met.

The scenario is the user is swiping a tab bar and if they go to the next tab and the condition is true it should disable further swiping. I have tried to put the tab bar in a stack with an Absorb pointer container on top but if they don't let go of the original gesture (i.e. they got to the new tab but didnt let go of the screen) it still allows them to drag through it.

is there anyway to stop the original swipe gesture?

i found this cancel method but i have no idea how to access it

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/Drag/cancel.html

Comment: try using dispose().Something similar is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759920/flutter-do-i-need-to-call-gesturerecognizer-dispose-in-statelesswidget-textspa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no need to handle gesture out of the `TabBarView` simply change the `ScrollPhysics`.

Here a code example:

```
final isDisable = ValueNotifier(false);

tabController.animation?.addListener(() {

  //The scrolling will be disabled if the second tab is displayed so you can 
  //add your own logic, may be just checking tabController.index

  if (tabController.animation!.value == 1.0) {
    isDisable.value = true;
  }
});

return Scaffold(
  body: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: isDisable,
    builder: (context, bool value, child) => TabBarView(
      controller: tabController,

      // changing the physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics will disable scrolling
      physics: value
          ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
          : AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

      children: children,
    ),
  ),
);
```